# How to make an object follow the screen on scroll?

Tags: html, css

Okay, that was a pretty ambiguous title, but in essence, this is what I want to be able to do: have an object start out at `x, y` and not move until the document has scrolled so much that the object is at the top of the screen.  Then, I want it to behave exactly like an object with the `position:fixed;` property set.  In other words, I want it to behave like the StackOverflow sidebar when you ask a new question: until the sidebar reaches the top of the screen, it stays put.  After that, it follows you.

Comment: The following tutorial may help you out: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help ^^